# how to use webRTC on android studio for video live streaming

Tags: android, video-streaming, webrtc

I passed three weeks searching how to create a video live call for my android app (using android studio), but can't find exactly what I'm looking for, I don't want to use something like quikbox or snitch because it's my final year project and I have to do it programatically, I find that webRTC for android can be used but unfortunately I didn't understand how to use it.

So please can anyone help me with any things.

Answer (score 0):

This is unfortunately something that's still hard. The team is working on it though: see https://bugs.chromium.org/p/webrtc/issues/detail?id=6328 for progress.

There's also https://bugs.chromium.org/p/webrtc/issues/detail?id=6804 that has resulted in this bot archiving .aar builds: https://build.chromium.org/p/client.webrtc.fyi/builders/Android%20Archive which should make it easier to consume the library.